# Suppose $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix. How many entries of $A$ can be chosen independently if ...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following problem:

> Suppose $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix. How many entries of $A$ can be chosen independently if
>
> a) $A$ is symmetric
>
> b) $A$ is skew-symmetric ($A^T = -A$)?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify what is meant by "chosen independently"?

Comment: a) $4+3+2+1$
b) $3+2+1$

Comment: For instance: if $A$ is skew-symmetric, our choice of $A_{21}$ *depends on* our choice of $A_{12}$.  If $A_{21} = -1$ we must have $A_{12} = 1$.  So, these entries cannot be chosen independently.

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela, that doesn't help the person asking at all, and is also false.

Comment: @DjalalOunadjela b) 3 + 2 + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "chosen independently" means that you can pick it without being constrained by previous choices. For instance, consider question (a): if you pick the number 5 to sit in the top right corner, then this forces the entry in the bottom left corner to also be 5. Thus, you cannot choose the entry in the bottom left corner anymore. However, choosing an entry for the top left corner does not force anything else.

(You will likely learn at a later stage that this question is really asking you to determine the dimension of the space of symmetric respectively skew-symmetric matrices.)

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to explain using $2 \times 2$ matrix.

In general, a $2 \times 2$ matrix can be written as $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$. Without restriction, we get to choose $4$ numbers.

If we impose the condition that it must be a symmetric matrix, it must be of the form of $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & d\end{bmatrix}$. We must have $b=c$. Hence, we get to choose $3$ numbers, $a, b,$ and $d$.

If we impose the condition that it must be antisymmetric, then it must be of the form of $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & b \\ -b & 0\end{bmatrix}$. We only get to choose $1$ number.

Can you do it for a $4 \times 4$ matrix?

Comment: yikes, thanks for spoting the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple let $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix

- $A$ is symetric means $b=c$. Thus, once you've chosen the value of $b$, you only have one choice for the value of $c$ : it is $b$. But the values of $a$ and $d$ can be chosen as you wish, since they won't play a part in the symetry of $A$. Thus, there is $3$ entries of $A$ that can be chosen independantly : $a,b,d$ (or, by symetry, $a,c,d$).
- $A$ is skew-symetric means $a=-a$, $b=-c$, $c=-b$ and $d=-d$. How many entries can be chosen independantly ? For example, can you chose any value for $a$ ? for $d$ ? And once you've chosen $b$, what are the choices left for $c$ ?

The reasonning is the same for a $n\times n$ matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\ a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44}\end{bmatrix} $$
(1) If $A=A^{T}$. Clearly we have to choose 4 diagonal entries independently. Now consider all the 6 independent entries lower to main diagonal. If we know these entries we know all the 6 entries above to main diagonal. Hence answer is 6+4=10.

(2) If $A=-A^{T}.$ This time diagonal entries are all zero, i.e,  $a_{11}=a_{22}=a_{33}=a_{44}=0$. Only need is to choose either lower (or upper) 6 entries to main diagonal. Hence answer is 6.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the problem isn't very precise.

What it's getting at is that if you have, e.g., a symmetric matrix and know, say, the $(1, 2)$ entry, you also know the $(2, 1)$ entry, as $A_{ij} = (A^{\top})_{ij} = A_{ji}$. Thus the $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 1)$ entries (or more generally, the $(i, j)$ and $(j, i)$ entries, $i \neq j$) *cannot* be chosen independently.

In the case of skew-symmetric matrices we similarly have $A_{ij} = -A_{ji}$, and this implies that $A_{ii} = 0$ for all $i$.$^*$ So, the diagonal entries, $A_{ii}$ cannot be chosen at all.

We can phrase the original question a little more precisely. To do so, observe that the set of symmetric matrices constitutes a vector $4 \times 4$ matrices (endowed with usual matrix addition and scalar multiplication). Then, part (a) just asks for the dimension of this vector space. Part (b) can be interpreted similarly.

(*This assertion is only true when the underlying field from which the matrix entries are chosen does not have characteristic $2$, but probably the entries in this case are meant to be taken from $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$.)

Answer (score -2):

a) $4+3+2+1$

b) $3+2+1$ and the diagonal must be $0$

Comment: Your answer for (b) is incorrect.

Comment: thank you, is it now correct  ?

Comment: The answer is now correct, but it still does not help the asker, who specifically requested an explanation for what it means to "choose entries independently".